# Deleting blank spaces to write only one long string in Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: linux, shell, whitespace, tr, blank-line

I am working in Ubuntu and I am trying to delete all blank spaces in my file to get only one long string.
My file has `\t` and `\n` in one text that it is supposed to be a long string made of letters only (it is a genomic sequence). It looks like:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAGTCGCTCGGAACCTGCTTCAAG
AGTCTAGCTCGATAAAGCTTAGATCTGATATAGATGAGATAGAGTGA
GGATCTTGATCTTTAGGAG
```

Thus, I want to eliminate ALL the `\n` and `\t` and write a unique string with all pieces written one after the other, with no spaces at all and without deleting any letter only the spaces, to finally get something like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAGTCGCTCGGAACCTGCTTCAAGAGTCTAGCTCGATAAAGCTTAGATCTGATATAGATGAGATAGAGTGAGGATCTTGATCTTTAGGAG
```

I tried with:

```
tr -d "\t\r\n\v\f" < file_spaces.txt > fileNOspaces.txt
```

but It did not work and I see exactly the same `\n` and `\t`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$ cat foo
foo     bar     baz
qux
quux
quuux
$ tr -d '\t\n' < foo
foobarbazquxquuxquuux
```

Comment: Ouh... It didn't work. Thank you anyway and ... Sorry because I don't have expertise in programming.

Comment: Even your example only deletes the (\n) but there are tab spaces (\t) yet: foo bar bazquxquuxquuux ... In my file there are the same spaces yet.

Comment: The spaces you see in the output can't be tabs `\t` since these are removed by `tr`. Try to remove `\r`, too.

Comment: I removed any kind of "spacer" with: tr -d '\t\n\r\v\f\b\a' < foo
but I got the same: foo     bar     bazquxquuxquuux

Comment: APPARENTLY this method finally worked! I apologise, I have forgotten to change some file names. Curiously it didn't work with the foo file, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Below script will fulfill your requirement. The while loop will make all the lines into a single line separated by space and `sed` command will remove all the space and finally produce one single line.

```
line=$(cat file_spaces.txt |  while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done)
echo $line |sed 's/ //g' > fileNOspaces.txt
```

or

```
 line=$(while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done < t1.txt)
 echo $line
 echo $line |sed 's/ //g' > fileNOspaces.txt
```

Your final output would be:-

```
 AAAAAAAAAAAAAGTCGCTCGGAACCTGCTTCAAGAGTCTAGCTCGATAAAGCTTAGATCTGATATAGATGAGATAGAGTGAGGATCTTGATCTTTAGGAG
```

Also always provide full path if running from different place, like `/full/path/file_spaces.txt`

Comment: It deleted all lines... there are nothing more than one \n and one \t in the output "fileNOspaces.txt", but in a short example (as given with foo) it worked... I don't understand.

Comment: just run this `while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done < t1.txt` and check what output it generate.

Comment: Uhm... No, it did the same, it gives a file with 0 kb.

Comment: just run `while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done < file_spaces.txt ` it should not create any file just print in consul.

Comment: Finally I got the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply use:

```
tr -d '[:space:]' < file_spaces.txt > fileNOspaces.txt
```

From the man [isspace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html):

```
checks for white-space characters.  In the "C" and "POSIX"
locales, these are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'),
carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical
tab ('\v').
```